# How can I create this effect with CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using [react-text-loop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-loop) and I'm trying to create an effect that loops through a series of genres before finally landing on one. However, I'm struggling with CSS. I want to have "| COMPOSER" horizontally centered on the page with a list of adjectives scrolling by, to the left of the "|". Currently, the "GENRE | COMPOSER" is centered on the page, but every time the length "GENRE" changes, the position of "| COMPOSER" moves to the right to make room for the new word.

How can I make it so that "| COMPOSER" is static, "GENRE" is right aligned and the length of the word changes to the left?

If it's helpful at all, I've been using Bootstrap for the layout of other components.

Here's my code so far:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import TextLoop from "react-text-loop";
import { useTimer } from "react-timer-hook";

const RandomList = (props) => {
  let called = 0;
  let timestamp = props.time;
  timestamp.setSeconds(timestamp.getSeconds() + 0.5);
  const [currWord, setCurrWord] = useState("");
  let primary = ["Film", "TV", "Video Game", "Animation"];
  const words = [
    "Film",
    "TV",
    "Video Game",
    "Animation",
    "Interactive",
    "Theme Park",
    "Multimedia",
    "Multi-Genre",
    "Library",
    "Musical Theater"
  ];
  const { isRunning, restart } = useTimer({
    autoStart: true,
    expiryTimestamp: timestamp,
    onExpire: () => {
      let nextWord;
      if (primary.includes(currWord)) {
        nextWord =
          props.secondary[Math.floor(Math.random() * props.secondary.length)];
        props.removeItemSecondary(nextWord);
        console.log(props.secondary);
        setCurrWord(nextWord);
      } else {
        nextWord =
          props.primary[Math.floor(Math.random() * props.primary.length)];
        props.removeItemPrimary(nextWord);
        console.log(props.primary);
        setCurrWord(nextWord);
      }
      const time = new Date();
      time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 3);
      restartSecond(time);
    },
  });

  const { restart: restartSecond } = useTimer({
    autoStart: false,
    expiryTimestamp: timestamp,
    onExpire: () => {
      called++;
      const time = new Date();
      time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 0.5);
      timestamp += 2000;
      restart(time);
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      {isRunning ? (
        <TextLoop interval="10" style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}>
          {words.map((word, index) => (
            <p style={{ textAlign: "right" }} key={index}>
              {word.toUpperCase()}
            </p>
          ))}
        </TextLoop>
      ) : (
        <span>{currWord.toUpperCase()} </span>
      )}
      {" | "}
      COMPOSER
    </>
  );
};

export default RandomList;
```